# 403 error code when using axios.post to Django endpoint in React app

Tags: python, django, reactjs, csrf, http-status-code-403

I am getting a 403 when I try to make a simple post request to a django view from within my react app. Here is my code:

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def test_view():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        return HttpResponse(request.body)
```

Login.js (React component)

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

//React constructor {

  test_view() {
      const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
      const config = {
        headers: {'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN': csrftoken},
      }
      axios.post('/prototype/hello/', {firstName: 'Fred'}, config)
        .then(res => {console.log("Test res: " + res.data)});
  }
//}
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^hello', views.test_view, name='test-view'),
```

Is it possible that the 'js-cookie' library isn't working? I don't have {% csrf_token %} anywhere because I'm not using a django template other than index.html. Instead, I have the @csrf_protect decorator. I think that is what I'm supposed to do based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/).

Comment: you don't have to use csrf_protect if you didn't disable csrfmiddleware. and have you confirm that the cookies did get the csrf_token ?

Answer (score 10):

Simply, set the below settings. Nothing else is required.

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```